# Why data failed to save to MySQL from URL parameter value?

Tags: php, mysql, database, url, mysqli

I cannot figure out why the parameter from the value are **not saving on the MySQL** database. My connection string is working (config.php). But on MySQL database, it is 000-00-00 or 0.000000 [image: (Please click to see the image)] The data are not saving. What do you think is the problem here?

This is my **URL parameter**: `http://crbphil-001-site1.1tempurl.com/adddata.php?
    addday=2017/10/04&addhour=01:31:00&addlati=14.779623&addlongti=120.993705`

**adddata.php**

```
<?php 
//Connect to MySQL
include("config.php");
//Prepare Query
$query = "INSERT INTO track (tr_date, tr_time, latitude, longitude) VALUES ('".urlencode($_GET["addday"])."','".urlencode($_GET["addhour"])."','".urlencode($_GET["addlati"])."','".urlencode($_GET["addlongti"])."')";

//Execute Query
mysqli_query($connect, $query);
?>
```

**config.php**

```
<?php 
$username = "a2a8e2_itrack";  //mysql username
$password = "******"; //mysql password
$servername="mysql****.hostbuddy.com";
$dbname = "db_a2a8e2_itrack";

$connect = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$selected = mysqli_select_db($connect, $dbname);
?>
```

Comment: Share your sample URL with parameter

Comment: what happens if you remove `urlencode` and are you trying to decode or encode?

Comment: It's SQL, not a URL… `urlencode` is unsuitable.

Comment: You never look at the return value of `mysqli_query`. You never check for database errors with `mysqli_error`. How should we know what the problem is if you don't even look for it?

Comment: `urlencode($_GET["addday"])` will output as `2017%2F10%2F04`. And, table column can't take this value as data type is of date type. You have to convert it to date format first.

Comment: Also, please care to not run into big problems with SQL injections.. http://bobby-tables.com - please use prepared statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `urlencode` which is changing the format of the data.
For example, you are passing `addday=2017/10/04` BUT 
`urlencode($_GET["addday"]` gives `2017%2F10%2F04`

Simply remove urlencode and use just `$_GET`.

So your insert query becomes this :

```
$query = "INSERT INTO track (tr_date, tr_time, latitude, longitude)
          VALUES ('".$_GET["addday"]."', '".$_GET["addhour"]."', '".$_GET["addlati"]."', '".$_GET["addlongti"]."')";
```

Comment: You shouldn't provide an SQL-injection-friendly code block in your answer